# Proving that a hypersurface is rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the algebraic set $V(F)$ in $\mathbb{A}^4_\mathbb{C}$, where $
F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) + h(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, $g(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ and $h(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ are homogeneous polynomials of degrees 4 and 3 respectively and $F$ is irreducible. Any hints on proving that $V(F)$ is rational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The birational map $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb C)--\to V(F): [v]\mapsto -\frac {
h(v)}{g(v)}\cdot v \; $ does it.

Comment: And by $f$ you mean $F$? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected  my typo.